# Using pushwoosh with multiple target apps

Tags: ios, pushwoosh

I have an IOS application which has two targets, and each target has its own .plist file... I thought pushwoosh would get the "Pushwoosh_APPID" from the .plist which my target is set but it didn't actually...

Is there a way to set pushwoosh to get the "Pushwoosh_APPID" from another .plist file?

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also initialize PushNotificationManager with the following code:

```
+ (void)initializeWithAppCode:(NSString *)appCode appName:(NSString *)appName;
```

I.e.

```
[PushNotificationsManager initializeWithAppCode:@"XXXX-XXXX" appName:@"AppName"];
```

Do this first thing in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions function.